# ESP32 preferences. One error returned, all others work. SOLVED

Tags: esp32, code-review

I am using the Preferences.h library in my Arduino code. I initialize some values. I save them with the preference library. I then modify all the values, then read back the original saved values.

All the values, **except one**, are restored with the associated get instruction. The one still shows the modified value. I can't see why it is wrong.

Can someone point out my error with calibratedWeight? And if you see some other general errors with the code, please point them out. (I'm not a programmer)

```
#include <Preferences.h>

Preferences preferences;

int currentFile = 1;
int outputRate = 10;           // milliSeconds
float outputGain = 1.23;
int zeroWeight = 900;          // dac value to produce Zero on scale
int calibratedWeight = 2800;   // dac value equal to 100lb calibration weight.
float DACmultiplier = 20.1;  

//---------------------------------------
void savePreferences() {
    preferences.begin("ScaleSetup", false);      // false for read/write
    preferences.putInt("currentFile", currentFile);
    preferences.putInt("outputRate", outputRate);
    preferences.putFloat("outputGain", outputGain);
    preferences.putInt("zeroWeight", zeroWeight);
    preferences.putInt("calibratedWeight", calibratedWeight);  // ???
    preferences.putFloat("DACmultiplier", DACmultiplier);
    preferences.end();
}

//---------------------------------------
void getPreferences() {
    preferences.begin("ScaleSetup", false);        // false for read/write

    currentFile = preferences.getInt("currentFile", currentFile);
    outputRate = preferences.getInt("outputRate", outputRate);
    outputGain = preferences.getFloat("outputGain", outputGain);
    zeroWeight = preferences.getInt("zeroWeight", zeroWeight);
    calibratedWeight = preferences.getInt("calibratedWeight", calibratedWeight);  // ???
    DACmultiplier = preferences.getFloat("DACmultiplier", DACmultiplier);
    preferences.end();
}

//============================================
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  preferences.begin("ScaleSetup", false);        // false for read/write
  preferences.clear();
  preferences.end();
  delay(90);

  savePreferences();
  Serial.println("\n save preferences");
  Serial.println("\n Original asigned values. \n");

  Serial.printf("currentFile: %i\n", currentFile);
  Serial.printf("outputRate: %i\n", outputRate);
  Serial.printf("outputGain: %f\n", outputGain);
  Serial.printf("zeroWeight: %i\n", zeroWeight);
  Serial.printf("calibratedWeight: %i\n", calibratedWeight);  // ???
  Serial.printf("DACmultiplier: %f\n", DACmultiplier);

  Serial.println("\n modify values. \n");

  currentFile = 5;
  outputRate = 50;           // milliSeconds
  outputGain = 0.45;
  zeroWeight = 1333;         // dac value to produce Zero on scale
  calibratedWeight = 2200;   // dac value equal to 100lb calibration weight.
  DACmultiplier = 12.34;

  Serial.printf("currentFile: %i\n", currentFile);
  Serial.printf("outputRate: %i\n", outputRate);
  Serial.printf("outputGain: %f\n", outputGain);
  Serial.printf("zeroWeight: %i\n", zeroWeight);
  Serial.printf("calibratedWeight: %i\n", calibratedWeight);  // ???
  Serial.printf("DACmultiplier: %f\n", DACmultiplier);

  Serial.println("\n Get original saved preferences. \n");
  getPreferences();

  Serial.printf("currentFile: %i\n", currentFile);
  Serial.printf("outputRate: %i\n", outputRate);
  Serial.printf("outputGain: %f\n", outputGain);
  Serial.printf("zeroWeight: %i\n", zeroWeight);
  Serial.printf("calibratedWeight: %i\n", calibratedWeight);  // ???
  Serial.printf("DACmultiplier: %f\n", DACmultiplier);

//  Serial.println("Restarting in 10 seconds...");
  delay(10000);
//  ESP.restart();
}

//============================================
void loop() {}
```

The following is the result.

```
 save preferences

 Original asigned values. 

currentFile: 1
outputRate: 10
outputGain: 1.230000
zeroWeight: 900
calibratedWeight: 2800
DACmultiplier: 20.100000

 modify values. 

currentFile: 5
outputRate: 50
outputGain: 0.450000
zeroWeight: 1333
calibratedWeight: 2200
DACmultiplier: 12.340000

 Get original saved preferences. 

currentFile: 1
outputRate: 10
outputGain: 1.230000
zeroWeight: 900
calibratedWeight: 2200
DACmultiplier: 20.100000
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but then I'm not familiar with this library.  begin() [appears to return a success/fail](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/1.0.4/libraries/Preferences/src/Preferences.h#L28) and various put function can [return short values on failure](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/1.0.4/libraries/Preferences/src/Preferences.h#L34).  Just as a sanity check, I would make sure all these are returning expected values.

Comment: I wonder if I corrupted something earlier and it is messed up now. I thought the preferences.clear(); function might fix that if it was the problem. I will try and test for success/fail somehow. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: i would debug this kind of a problem by renaming `calibratedWeight` to `abc123` just to see if it is related to the name

Comment: When I change it to abc123 it returns the correct value. Then when I change all the abc123 back to calibratedWeight it then does not work, it returns the same result I originally showed. I think changing it to abc123 made a new entry rather than overwrite calibratedWeight. And when I went back to calibratedWeight the problem remains. But I thought preferences.clear(); should have cleared everything.

Comment: I changed preferences.begin("ScaleSetup", false);   to preferences.begin("Scale_Setup", false);   I was sure this would fix it, but I get the same result.

Comment: Maybe I need to Reboot Windows. :)

Comment: I'm sure I know what the problem is. 16 characters when 15 characters is the maximum allowed.

Comment: "Note: Namespace name is limited to 15 chars"  I don't understand Namespace, but I guess the same applies to variable names. It works with a 15 character name.

Comment: You're allowed to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: So, *did* this `preferences.putInt("calibratedWeight", calibratedWeight);` return `0`?

Comment: I was about to try that but I had thought about the length. I still want to do a couple of tests, but at the time I was more concerned about getting the rest of my code done. I will post more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the comments above I said I thought the problem was with the variable name length.

Today I tried the debug option and then ran the code. And the following error message was included in the com output.

[E][Preferences.cpp:163] putInt(): nvs_set_i32 fail: calibratedWeight **KEY_TOO_LONG**

So I guess I was right. I didn't know anything about the debug option before.